# Using a Pearson Chi-Squared to test if residuals are normally distributed

Tags: multiple-regression, chi-squared-test, normality-assumption

I'm was trying to create an exercise, where the 'student' would take the residuals of a multiple linear regression ($y=x\beta+u$), and then test if the residuals are normally distributed (assuming iid) using a Pearson Chi-Squared test.

However, someone told me that we can't do this because the residuals are not observations of the error term, but also include the estimation errors, and as such they $corr(\hat u_i,\hat u_j)\neq 0$...

Is there a way to salvage the original exercise?

Comment: With a sufficiently large number of observations (perhaps ten or more), the mutual correlations can be ignored.  But formal testing of normality is, at best, useful for automatic screening of many regressions.  The standard approach of reviewing a QQ plot is far more informative (and, implicitly, also ignores the slight correlations among the residuals).  So, maybe a better exercise pedagogically would focus on interpreting QQ plots of residuals.

Comment: For future reference https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498156/how-to-prove-that-non-diagonal-elements-of-hat-matrix-from-regression-are-limi

Comment: @whuber thanks for your comment. I've put a link to an answer where they prove that the sum of the squares of the off-diagonal elements of the Hat matrix ($H$) along a column is at most 0.25. Is this the reason why we can ignore the mutual correlations?

Comment: I don't see that.  From the fact that the residuals sum to zero you can conclude [their average correlation is $-1/(n-1):$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137178) that's pretty good guidance right there.

Comment: @whuber but in that answer, you're assuming that the variables are identically distributed and similarly for their bivariate distribution... Also, in what sense do you say on average?

Comment: A simple modification of that answer will prove the point.  You only need to assume homoscedasticity (which isn't quite true, either, but is usually a reasonable approximation).

Comment: @whuber $-1/(n-1) = \frac{\sum^n_{i\neq j} \rho_{ij}}{n(n-1)}\approx E(\rho_{ij, i\neq j})$ this?